# <audio> HTML5 element state using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, html5-audio

I was wondering if there was any Javascript method that could help getting information on the state of an audio tag:

- is the audio playing
- has it stopped
- is it muted
- is it paused

and the sort. I know that we can use `play()`, `pause()` and others but not quite sure on how to check in the script that the audio is playing in order to trigger another event/action maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can check a number of attributes on the HTML5 media elements, a list of which you can find in the [W3C HTML5 Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#media-element) itself.

Under the "playback state" list you can see such attributes as `paused`, `muted`, `ended` etc.

Comment: thnak you I went there but did not see this, I suppose I need to open my eyes more :)

Comment: You're welcome! I wrote a book on the thing so scoured those particular parts of the specification quite thoroughly!

Comment: may I ask what the book is about precisely? I am doing a dissertation on HTML5 so it may be helpful...

Comment: It's a book on HTML5 Multimedia. Check out http://html5multimedia.com for further information.